# How can I automatically run an AppleScript when Safari.app starts?

Tags: safari, applescript, startup

Basically I want make sure I execute a custom written .applescript every time Safari is opened.

I tried adding the script to the "~/Library/Scripts/Applications/Safari" folder but that doesn't seem to automatically do it.

As a workaround I can probably just write an AppleScript that both starts Safari and runs my custom stuff. I just wanted to check whether there's a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Putting stuff in the **~/LibraryScripts/Applications** folder just makes them available when the particular application is active.

In addition to your alias that runs the script and Safari, you could use some AppleScriptObj-C in a background application (maybe run via login items) that registers for **NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification** notifications to get the names of applications as they are launched.  This would also have the advantage of seeing when Safari gets launched other than from your alias, such as via various document links (Mail, PDFs, etc):

```
use framework "Foundation"

my addObserver:me selector:"appLaunchNotification:" |name|:(current application's NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification) object:(missing value)

on appLaunchNotification:notification -- an application was launched
  # notification's userInfo contains the application that was launched
  set applicationInfo to NSWorkspaceApplicationKey of notification's userInfo -- NSRunningApplication
  set appName to (localizedName of applicationInfo) as text
  -- do your thing depending on appName
end appLaunchNotification:
```